# Material-UI Data Visualization

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

It looks like Material-UI doesn't support any form of data visualization? Does anyone know of any libraries that are both responsive and material-ui-esque in design and aesthetic?

Answer (score 2):

For future guys seeing this query, you might wanna take a look at DevExtreme Reactive React Chart component for your data visualization needs.

They work well with Material UI and the plugin is highly scalable in terms of different visualization requirements.

https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/chart/

Answer (score 1):

I have found https://github.com/reactjs/react-chartjs fits in quite nicely with the MUI aesthetic. You can use Mui theme to set colors of graphs etc... You do need to also include the chartjs library as below in package.json

`"dependencies": {
    "chart.js": "^1.1.1",
    "react-chartjs": "^1.2.0"
  }`

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still looking, I would highly recommend using ApexCharts https://apexcharts.com/ and customizing the look to be more MUI-esque. It's open source, responsive and highly customizable. It's by far the best I've found.